# Update multiple MySQL rows from another table

Tags: mysql

Ok I have two tables: articles and posts.

In articles, I have the "image" column where each entry has a name for the image.

In the posts table, I have the "post_image" column where I want to put all the values from the articles table, with the matching article id.

This is what I'm trying to do but of course it spits out an error since it's more than one value. I know it should be a JOIN but I get lost with joins. Any help?

```
UPDATE posts SET post_image = (
SELECT image FROM articles, posts WHERE article_id = ID
)
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE posts SET post_image = (SELECT image FROM articles WHERE article_id = ID LIMIT 1)
```

And all it does is update all the entries of "post_image" with the first value of "articles".

Comment: the set clause needs only one value to assign to post_image on each row. you should filter the subquery to return only one row for the currently updating row. In fact, there's no need to join with posts, since it's the table you are updating.

Comment: I know what you mean, I updated my post about the LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was doing the wrong thing, it was much simpler than that. Here's what finally worked for me:

```
UPDATE posts, articles
SET posts.post_image = articles.image
WHERE posts.ID = articles.article_id
```